# Changing label font color in Plotly treemap

Tags: python, plotly, treemap

Does anyone know how to change the font color of treemap plots in Plotly? 
This is a sample code from the tutorial which automatically makes font color in the fist panel white and the rest black.

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.tips()
fig = px.treemap(df, path=['day', 'time', 'sex'], values='total_bill')
fig.show()
```

Also, I couldn't figure out how the figure size is adjusted.

Answer (score 1):

With the same given example, this is your treemap:

[image]

Now, you can add this line:

```
fig.data[0]['textfont']['color'] = "yellow"
```

Your plot becomes:

[image]